# How to create mesh map from list

Tags: java, guava

This is what I want at the end:

```java
Multimap<String, String> meshMap =
    ImmutableMultimap.<String, String>builder()
        .putAll("1", "2", "3")
        .putAll("2", "1", "3")
        .putAll("3", "1", "2")
        .putAll("a", "b")
        .putAll("b", "a")
        .build();
```

Is there a way to do it more elegantly with stream() or another Guava helpers, using 2 lists?

```java
Set<String> group1 = ImmutableSet.of("1", "2", "3");
Set<String> group2 = ImmutableSet.of("a", "b");
Multimap<String, String> meshMap = // ???
```

I am using Java 8 but if better way is available only in newer version of Java, I would appreciate to learn that too.

Comment: Your question is not clear, do you want to generate combinations from first two sets and store them in a Multimap, under what key?

Comment: Sorry about the ambiguity. I posted an answer to clarify what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

Posting an answer to my question to clarify my question, and also suggest at least one way to do it.

```
List<Set<String>> groups = List.of(
        ImmutableSet.of("1", "2", "3"),
        ImmutableSet.of("a", "b")
);

var meshMapBuilder = ImmutableMultimap.<String, String>builder();

groups.forEach(group -> {
    group.forEach(item -> {
        var groupExceptItem = group.stream()
                .filter(x -> !x.equals(item))
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
        meshMapBuilder.putAll(item, groupExceptItem);
    });
});

var meshMap = meshMapBuilder.build();
```